# Variable number of instances for Multiple Instance Learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification, multiple-instances

I am trying to do a Multiple Instance Learning for a binary classification problem, where each bag of instances has an associated label 0/1. However, the different bags have different numbers of instances. One solution is to take the minimum of all the instance numbers of the bag. For eg-

```
Bag1 - 20 instances, Bag2- 5 instances, Bag3 - 10 instances .... etc
```

I am taking the minimum i.e- 5 instances from all the bags. However, this technique discards all the other instances from other bags which might contribute to the training.

Is there any workaround/algorithm for MIL where variable instance numbers for bags could be handled?

Comment: try recurrent neural networks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `RaggedTensors` for this. They're mostly used in NLP work, since sentences have variable numbers of words (and paragraphs have variable numbers of sentences etc.). But there's nothing special about ragged tensors that limits them to this domain.

See [the tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) for more information. Not all layers or operations will work, but you can use things like Dense layers to build a Sequential or Functional (or even custom) model, if this works for you.